# Bookmark a page

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, bookmarks

How can we bookmark a page on clicking a button or a link button in flex using actionscript

Answer (score 1):

A working example based on the information in previous answers:

**bookmarks.js** (add this to your html-template directory):

```
 function CreateBookmarkLink(title, url) 
 {
    if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
        window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url,"");
    } else if( window.external ) { // IE Favorite
        window.external.AddFavorite( url, title); }
    else if(window.opera && window.print) { // Opera Hotlist
        return true; }
 }
```

Then add this line to **index.template.html:**

```
<script src="bookmarks.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

Now you have javascript code "wrapping" your Flex application which can be called by this code (**bookmarks.mxml**):

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function AddBookmark() : void
            {
                ExternalInterface.call("CreateBookmarkLink", 
                   "Stack Overflow", 
                   "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button x="10" y="10" label="Bookmark!" click="AddBookmark()"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Tested on IE.

Comment: This Firefox method doesn't work because it forces the bookmark to open in the sidebar - which is not the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use javascript for that. Just create a javascript function to bookmark a page in your html file that is hosting the swf and then call that function from inside the swf using ExternalInterface.

Here's an example of a javascript function for bookmarking: http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/01/add-to-favorites-ie-bookmark-firefox.html

Here's the Flex docs on how to use ExternalInterface: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/docs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001009.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do that from actionscript directly. However, you can invoke javascript from actionscript unsing the `ExternalInterface` class, and the web is teeming with javascript functions to create bookmarks.  Take a look at [this](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/01/add-to-favorites-ie-bookmark-firefox.html), for example (I have not tested it).